# Amazon EC2: How to enable MySQL and SQLITe

Tags: php, pdo, amazon-ec2

The EC2 instance I have been given has php7 installed but without `mysql` and `sqlite3` modules thus unable to use.

I tried `sudo yum install php-pdo` but it gave error:

```
amzn-main                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates                                             | 2.5 kB     00:00     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 for package: php-pdo-5.3.29-1.8.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.3.29-1.8.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: php70-common-7.0.21-1.24.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts php-common < 5.5.22-1.98
```

Comment: I think installing `mbstring` and `mcrypt` will help you out.

Comment: Why? can you elaborate how will it help?

Comment: Mysql uses these packages. I am making a guess and asking you to give it a try.

Comment: The mysql module finally has been removed from php7, so you are not going to use that one. The rest you should be able to enable by tweaking php.ini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the php7 packages. php-* currently installs PHP 5.6 extensions, that’s why you get the dependency conflict error

e.g.

```
yum install php70-pdo
```

The various MySQL extensions are in the  package `php70-mysqlnd`

Comment: Shouldn't it be like php7.0-pdo? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Not with Amazon Linux

Comment: I have EC2 with php 5.6 and php7.1 And when I install any packages I have to write `php5.6-pdo` or `php7.1-pdo`

Comment: @MichelFeldheim I can see SQLITe here (http://ec2-52-38-195-145.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/test.php) but not mysql

Comment: @Volatil3 You need to restart apache to get these packages into effect.
As a root user on terminal, type this command, `apachectl restart`

Comment: Dude.. Read what I have written

Comment: @volatil3 check the package php70-mysqlnd